# Asp.net website developed using kentico cms causing "www" prefix issue

Tags: kentico

We are facing a weird issue specific only on one website even though we are hosting more than 150 websites on same server using Kentico CMS 11.

We have turned on "www" prefix settings from Kentico -> Urls & SEO for all the websites and all these sites are working without any issue.
But there is a specific website on which all the requests are getting redirected to home page if try to access with "www" prefix.

I have tried checking at code level and could not find any issue. If it would be code issue then it should appear for other websites as well.

We are using Azure app service for hosting our application so I have checked in application insight as well and could not get any lead as all the request which are logged for this specific websites are of home page.

Please help me in understanding if I need to see through this issue at some other place. I have checked with Client's IS team and they could not find any DNS settings difference when compared to other websites which are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the web.config file of this site. It may contain a wrong URL redirect associated with "www" so that probably this redirect just cuts all the path from URL.